# Python 3 reading and writing csv file and using dict to print row

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am reading huge csv file and take the last line for date and time.
I wrote below code and looking for enhancement or an optimized solution.

Following is my data:

> 2067458,XXXXXXXXXX,1006386,100.79.94.1,XXXX4,1,0,0,1,0,1,"XXXXX",Live,"Unknown",Unknown,Unknown,Unknown,_ROUTER_HAS_NO_RADIO_,
>   Unknown, Unknown, Unknown, Unknown, 2017-01-24, 16:03:43, , , , , , ,
>   , , , ,

This is my code

```
import csv
import datetime
import re

input_file = 'input22.csv'
output_file= 'temp.csv'

def main():
    with open(input_file,"r") as fileHandle:
         CSVreader = fileHandle.readlines()
         fileHandle.close()
         reader  = CSVreader[-1]

    with open ('temp.csv',"w") as fileHandle:
         fileHandle.write(reader)
         fileHandle.close()

    with open('temp.csv') as temp_file:
         readCSV = csv.reader(temp_file, delimiter=',')
         for row in readCSV:
             Date=(row[22])
             Time=(row[23])
             D=Date.strip()
             T=Time.strip()
             print ("{} {}".format(D,T))


main()
```

Comment: You can use ```pandas``` to read the csv directly in one line and get any column out.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Some issues I see right off the bat with your code--no need to close your file when you open it using a `with` block. The whole point of using context is that as soon as you leave the block the file is closed.

Eg;

```
with open ('temp.csv',"w") as fileHandle:
     fileHandle.write(reader)
     fileHandle.close()
```

Should just be;

```
with open ('temp.csv',"w") as fileHandle:
     fileHandle.write(reader)
```

That's it! Python handles closing the file for you.

Next, don't use `fh.readlines()`. That reads the whole file into memory and may crash your computer if the file is too big to fit into memory. Instead, [iterate over the file, as per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader). In this context, that looks like;

```
with open(input_file, "r") as fileHandle:
     CSVreader = csv.reader(fileHandle)
     for row in CSVreader:
         # do something with the row
```

Python will buffer your reads automatically, and will only keep a small part of the file in memory at once. Side note: The way you currently have it, you're reading the entire file into `CSVreader` which should really just be called `rows` or something, since this is *not* a `reader` object.

Finally, there's no need to pass the mode to the `open()` call in the first instance--you can use the same syntax that you use the second time you open `temp.csv`.

I believe this (untested) snippet accomplishes the same thing as yours, a little more succinctly and efficiently.

```
import csv
import datetime
import re

input_file = 'input22.csv'
output_file= 'temp.csv'

def main():
    last = list()  # scope this variable so that we may use it after the files have been closed
    with open(input_file) as input_fh, \
            open('temp.csv', 'w') as output_fh:
        reader = csv.reader(input_fh)
        writer = csv.writer(output_fh)
        # discard everything except the last line of output
        for row in reader:
            last = row
        writer.write(last)

    # print that last row with formatting
    D=last[22].strip()
    T=last[23].strip()
    print ("{} {}".format(D,T))

main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, you bring out my main concern to buffer up full lines in 1 variable. following code works with writer.writerows(last).